# Flutter WebViewFlutter o IframeElement | No puedo reproducir contenido en una pagina web de canales en vivo

Tags: html, flutter, dart, webview, jwplayer

Tengo el siguiente código simple de una aplicación Flutter:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      home: Scaffold(body: getWebPlayer()),
    );
  }

  getWebPlayer() {
    WebViewController controller = WebViewController();
    WebViewWidget webViewWidget = WebViewWidget(controller: controller);
    controller
        .loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://canales.online/en-vivo/espn-premium/'));
    return webViewWidget;
  }
}
```

El `body` del `Scaffold` es construido por un método que retorna un `WebViewWidget` que carga una pagina web donde se transmite un canal deportivo en vivo(Espn).

El **Problema** es el siguiente:
Cuando carga el reproductor web de la página salta un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obteniendo el siguiente **error** en consola:

> jwplayer.js:9 Encrypted Media access has been blocked because of a Feature Policy applied to the current document. See https://goo.gl/EuHzyv for more details.
>
> jwplayer.js:9 JW Player Error 102630. For more information see https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/api/errors-reference#102630

Pero solo ocurre en mi app web de Flutter, si abro el mismo link en Chrome, el video reproduce sin problemas.

También cabe destacar que la app web cuando se ejecuta lo hace en una instancia de Chrome.

Deduzco que se debe a algún tipo de problema con respecto a políticas y que deba ser configurado en la web app de Flutter.

Espero sus respuestas amigos.

Answer (score 0):

La web que intentas visualizar usa javascript. Para activarlo en el webview, debes agregar al controlador el setJavaScripMode(JavascripMode.unrestricted).
El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
  class MyAppPage extends StatefulWidget {
    const MyAppPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    State<MyAppPage> createState() => _MyAppPageState();
  }

  class _MyAppPageState extends State<MyAppPage> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        home: Scaffold(body: getWebPlayer()),
      );
    }

    getWebPlayer() {
      WebViewController controller = WebViewController();
      WebViewWidget webViewWidget = WebViewWidget(controller: controller);
      controller
        ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
        ..setNavigationDelegate(
          NavigationDelegate(
            onProgress: (int progress) {
              debugPrint('WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)');
            },
            onPageStarted: (String url) {
              debugPrint('Page started loading: $url');
            },
            onPageFinished: (String url) {
              debugPrint('Page finished loading: $url');
            },
            onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
              // Evita las páginas de publicidad
              debugPrint('blocking navigation to ${request.url}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            },
          ),
        )
        ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://canales.online/en-vivo/espn-premium/'));
      return webViewWidget;
    }
  }
```